# Talend migration Oracle to Postgres

Tags: oracle, postgresql, talend

I am using Talend studio, testing it for a simple migration from an Oracle database to a Postgres database.
The two connections are ok, but I got error on insert into the Postgres database because I believe Talend generates a sql query with Double quotes instead of simple quotes. Now, I have been looking around and I do not find some solutions. Very difficult for me to believe there is not simple solution for such a simple problem (though simple problems are often the most difficult to solve ...).

Comment: Can you show us that query and error message ? Doubling quotes `''` is standard/normal way to escape single quote in string literals. BTW: It is PostgreSQL or simply (nickname) Postgres, not postGres.

Comment: Thank you Grzegorz for correcting my Postgres style :), I'll sound more pro now. Here is the error message :[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3554
[statistics] connected
Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO "public"."snati" ("NUMER","NOTANDI_NUMER") VALUES (41,41) was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
[statistics] disconnected
Job Migration ended at 13:11 10/06/2011. [exit code=0]

Comment: Please edit your question rather than putting whole code into comment. I see nothing wrong with that query, it just uses (schema, table, columns) names in case sensitive manner. Could you follow "Call getNextException to see the cause" hint and provide more info about exception ?

Comment: Pitty it's not an error message from the postgres backend. In most cases postgres is setup to log query errors in it's logs so could you post what it says in the postgres logs?

Answer (score 1):

After some time,  I switched to Pentaho Kettle solution, that worked without any trouble. 
I would still like to thank you for your time.